# Plotting a ROC curve in scikit yields only 3 points

Tags: python, validation, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

**TLDR: scikit's `roc_curve` function is only returning 3 points for a certain dataset. 
Why could this be, and how do we control how many points to get back?**

I'm trying to draw a ROC curve, but consistently get a "ROC triangle".

```
lr = LogisticRegression(multi_class = 'multinomial', solver = 'newton-cg')
y = data['target'].values
X = data[['feature']].values

model = lr.fit(X,y)

# get probabilities for clf
probas_ = model.predict_log_proba(X)
```

Just to make sure the lengths are ok:

```
print len(y)
print len(probas_[:, 1])
```

Returns 13759 on both.

Then running:

```
false_pos_rate, true_pos_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y, probas_[:, 1])
print false_pos_rate
```

returns [ 0.          0.28240129  1.        ]

If I call threasholds, I get array([ 0.4822225 , -0.5177775 , -0.84595197]) (always only 3 points).

It is therefore no surprise that my ROC curve looks like a triangle.

What I cannot understand is **why scikit's `roc_curve` is only returning 3 points.** Help hugely appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the values in `probas_[:,1]`? Although it has length of 13759, it may only contain 3 values...

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did `[print pd.Series(probas_[:,1]).unique()]`, and indeed only 2 uniques (`[-0.84595197 -0.5177775 ]`) were returned

Comment: Glad it helps. Please accept the answer if you like.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The number of points depend on the number of unique values in the input. Since the input vector has only 2 unique values, the function gives correct output.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem with a different example. The mistake I made was to input the outcomes for *a given threshold* and not the **probabilities** in the argument `y_score` of `roc_curve`. It also gives a plot with three points but it is a mistake !

Comment: Here is an example of how to finish plotting the roc curve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67754984/670433

Answer (score 5):

I ran into same problem, and after reading the documentaion carefully I realized that the mistake is in:

```
probas_ = model.predict_log_proba(X)
```

Although, there were hints pointed by others by checking the uniqueness. It should be instead:

```
probas_ = model.decisions(X)
```

Comment: The documentation's example also uses Y_score= model.decision(x_test) after fitting the model and passes Y_score to roc_curve.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_display_object_visualization.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-miscellaneous-plot-display-object-visualization-py

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to get 1 point except (0,0) and (1,1).
I'm using mushrooms dataset from kaggle for a binary classification problem.
Procuring fpr and tpr from roc_curve, I'm getting 4 more points, though their value is more or less same.

> fpr = {0, 0, 0.02290076, 0.0267176, 0.832061, 1}
>
> tpr = {0, 0.0315361, 0.985758, 0.996948, 1, 1}

I'm not sure if we can consider this as 1 point because plotting the curve using this looks like the one shown in question.